# How to register handler for SettingsChanged event in Office Web Add-ins

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to use the **Excel.Setting** and **Excel.SettingCollection** objects in the Excel 1.4 requirement set. (Not the old Setting object from the shared Office.js APIs.) I can't get my handler for the **Excel.SettingCollection.onSettingsChanged** event to be registered. Below is my code (TypeScript). I run the `createSetting` method and I have verified that my setting is being added. Then I run the `changeSetting` method. There are no errors, but my handler never runs. Can anyone see what's wrong? Adding a second setting and deleting a setting also don't trigger the handler. (Other Excel 1.4 APIs work fine.)

```
async function createSetting() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            const settings = context.workbook.settings;
            settings.add("NeedsReview", true);
            settings.onSettingsChanged.add(onChangedSetting);
            await context.sync();
        });
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

handler:

```
async function onChangedSetting() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            console.log("handler ran");  // DOES NOT RUN
            await context.sync();
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

change setting method:

```
async function changeSetting() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            const settings = context.workbook.settings;

            // The settings.add function is also how you change a 
            // setting. There is no Excel.SettingCollection.setItem
            // or Excel.Setting.set method.
            settings.add("NeedsReview", false); // Change value
            await context.sync();
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've learned that this is a known bug. When a setting is changed with the new 1.4 APIs, the `onSettingsChanged` event is not triggered. I will update here when it is fixed.

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/69.